# Wordpress PHP multiple else statements

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a wordpress theme and i want to have some of the page templates with an extended header div tag so i can add extra things in.

This is the code i have:

```
<?php if (!is_page_template('page-homepage.php')) { echo "</div>"; } ?>
```

I want it so i can have alternatives to the page-homepage.php so for example page-team.php as i want that individual page template to not close the div yet either, i tried writing this but it just does every page:

```
<?php if (!is_page_template('page-homepage.php' or 'page-team.php')) { echo "</div>"; } ?>
```

Any ideas? My php skills are not very advanced!

thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a logical operation on two strings (`'page-homepage.php' or 'page-team.php'`) which evaluates to true, so the statement becomes:

```
<?php if (!is_page_template(true)) { echo "</div>"; } ?>
```

Try this instead:

```
<?php if (!is_page_template('page-homepage.php') && !is_page_template('page-team.php')) { echo "</div>"; } ?>
```